# Open password protected pdf file

Tags: android

I am developing a pdf reader[eBook Reader, which can display pdf file], as android don't have any native pdf viewer so i have to use third party pdf viewer. 
in that case i have choose the Adobe pdf  viewer for android. 
I can open pdf file which are stored in sdcard of my device. 
Now i want to open password protected pdf file from my application. 
If user wants to open password protected pdf file manually then use have to provide password while opening.

but i want to open those password pdf file from my application without any password prompt. 
Application provide the password,[apps knows the password] and without any password prompt, pdf will open.

currently if i want to open any password protected pdf file from my 
application then a password prompt is appeared and needs a password to open it.

I am using this code to open pdf from my stored pdf files in the SDCARD.

====

```
File pdfFile = new File(fileLocation); 
if (pdfFile.exists()) 
{ 
    Uri pdfFilepathUri = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    
    intent.setDataAndType(pdfFilepathUri, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
    try 
    { 
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
    { 
        Toast.makeText(this,"No Application Available to View PDF : "+fileLocation,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 
}
else Toast.makeText(this,"File cannot found : "+fileLocation,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

====

can anybody please help how can i provide the password from the application, 
so that it can open pdf file automatically without prompting any password window. ?

Answer (score 0):

> in that case i have choose the Adobe pdf viewer for android

What you choose is immaterial. It is what users choose that matters.

> but i want to open those password pdf file from my application without any password prompt.

Hopefully, this is not supported. Due to the way Android caches some `Intents` used for starting activities, any application would be able to steal the password.

Regardless, there is nothing in the `ACTION_VIEW` standard for this.

Comment: Thanks. for reply
**1** I have use the adobe pdf viewer for opening pdf file.
Actually i am developing an application where the stealing password is not a big deal, because it will be use locally as a standalone application.

Ok, so there is no way to avoiding the password prompting issue while opening the pdf file[which is password protected] from application ?
**a** Can u please give any idea so that i can by pass the password prompting while opening pdf file?
**b** As far i know, we can't view/display pdf docs within an android application rather than using 3rd party pdf reader, am i right?

Comment: @redikod: "I have use the adobe pdf viewer for opening pdf file" -- again, your users might use something else. "Can u please give any idea so that i can by pass the password prompting while opening pdf file?" -- AFAIK this is not possible with any PDF viewer app. Any PDF viewer that supports this is insecure.  You are welcome to contact the developers of every PDF viewer and ask them if they support it. "we can't view/display pdf docs within an android application rather than using 3rd party pdf reader, am i right?" -- correct.